# Any alternative method to find the file type as text other than doing it with extensions and mime type?

Tags: javascript

Finding the type of a file without using extensions`enter code here` and mime type.
 currently I am doing like this:

```
isFileTypeText : function (file){
            if(file !== ""){
                var fileName = file.name;
                var ext =  fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                console.log(ext);
                if(ext === 'txt' || ext === 'xml'|| ext === 'rtx' || ext === 'yaml' || ext === 'lic' || ext === 'json' || ext === 'log'){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is wrong with this way ?

Comment: What exactly is `file` in this context? If it is a [`File` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), then you can use `File.type`

Comment: if you upload a text file with .txt extension and keep the content as unicode data FIleReader Api is able to upload the content of the file but the content inside the file is not plain text . So i need an alternative way to find the type of a file based on the conent inside .

Comment: for .lic, .json  files File.type will come as blank but these are valid files for my application .

Comment: @KavyaHL : So make a check for a blank response, then check for those two options. Personally, I would check content, not file extension, but I also do not know what you are doing with the files.